# Sharepoint C# Client app how to open documents edit mode

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, csom

I am struggling the open documents on check out mode by using given path.
I created a client on C# I solved authentication problems to accessing to sharepoint. But I don't know how to open documents on edit mode.

```
    // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(docUrl); // using this opens documents on read only mode


    namespace Sp_Ctx{
      class Program {
        [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args){
        //if (args.Length < 1) { Console.WriteLine("SP_Ctx <url>"); return; }

        string targetSite = "https://x/y/z/";

        using (ClientContext ctx = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(targetSite))
        {
            if (ctx != null)
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web); // Query for Web
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = ctx.Web;

                var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@"/a/b/c");

                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // Execute
                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine(); }}}
```

Comment: This looks like a console app. What does opening a document in that context look like?

Comment: Yes, it is a console app.  If I use
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(docUrl);    
it opens the documents on read only mode. 
How can I open it for editing?

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding an "open for edit" protocol handler to the url.

For example:

```
ms-word:ofe|u|http://example.com/myTestDocument.docx
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25400742/1452528).